# react-native chat app "split" chat bubble

Tags: javascript, react-native, chat

I`m working on a chat app and I use [gifted chat](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat) . 
I want my bubble to contain both text and an image. That works fine but I'm not satisfied with the way it is split...

I want to have text on the left and the image on the right side.

Currently, my text is above the image:
[image]

This is the code for the content of the bubble:

```
<TouchableOpacity key={i} style={[styles.mapView, this.props.mapViewStyle]}>
  <View>
    <Text style = {styles.titleText}> {title}</Text>
    <Image style={[styles.image, this.props.imageStyle]} source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}/>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve text on the left and the image on the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `flexDirection` on `View`: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html#flex-direction
The default value is `column` so children are stacked vertically.

Comment: good to know. Thank you very much. It works with `<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use flex in View https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html You can also give desired alignment to text and image. By default direction is column so use flexDirection:'row'
Use the code below.

```
<TouchableOpacity key={i} style={[styles.mapView,     this.props.mapViewStyle]}>
  <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'row'}}>
    <View style={{flex:0.5}}>
        <Text style = {styles.titleText}> {title}</Text>
    </View>

    <View style={{flex:0.5}}>
       <Image style={[styles.image, this.props.imageStyle]} source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}/>
    </View>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. What is meaning of repeating accepting answer!!